# How to disable mouse touchpad while typing on Dell XPS 13 (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: touchpad, dell

I have a Dell XPS 13 9360 dual booted with Ubuntu LTS 16.04.

I was wondering how I could disable the mouse touchpad while I type. Any subtle touch to the touchpad completely throws off my typing. For example, the cursor shifts over to a random location and clicks, so then I start typing in the middle of a wrong sentence. I don’t experience this issue while I use Windows 10, however.

I’ve read on forums that this occurs because there are two touchpad drives installed or something. I tried a solution before, but when I changed the setting file, I was unable to boot Ubuntu and had to do a clean install. Since then, I’ve been a little more scared about changing files.

Are there any Dell XPS 13 9360 users out there that have figured this out?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

To Disable Touchpad Goto ->
System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad : in the Touchpad section switch from ON to OFF

Comment: I would like to still be able to use the touchpad though, not disable it completely.

Answer (score -1):

To Disable Touchpad Goto -> System Settings -> Mouse & Touchpad : in the Touchpad section switch from ON to OFF WORKS in 16.04! Other solutions didn't!